# Is it possible to adjust the pin image size of annotation ti.map

Tags: google-maps, titanium, apple-maps

I add the anntation like this

```
var annot= Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude: XXXXXXXXXXX,
        longitude: XXXXXXXXXX,
        title: 'myPlace',
        image: 'myPin.png',
        width:'100dp',// doesn't work
        height:'100dp'// doesn't work
    }); 
    this.mapView.addAnnotation(annot);
}
```

I would like to change the size of image though,
there seems no way to change.

So I need to edit the file size itself by image editor or something.
 Moreover images are show differently in Android or iPhone.
 So I need to make two size for each pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MapModule.createAnnotation({
    latitude : XXXX,
    longitude : XXXX,
    customView : Ti.UI.createView({
        width : widthImg,
        height : heightImg * 2,
        children : [Ti.UI.createView({
            top : 0,
            width : width,
            height : height,
            backgroundImage : "myPin.png"
        })]
    })
});
```